# Angular js same $scope in separated files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular js controller witch is getting bigger and bigger, so I want to separate some functions from it to separated files, but I cannot access $scope of that controller in other files. What is the best practice for doing this?

for example if this is my controller in app.js

```
formAppControllers.controller('mainController', function($scope,$translate) {});
```

I want to be able to use same $scope in functions.js file.

Comment: Pass the scope, use $rootScope?

Comment: Decomposition... abstract the problem to more smaller pieces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but I'd do this the other way around: I'll define services and use them in the controllers which are getting crowded. That way, you can avoid accessing the `$scope` elsewhere.

Something like `service.js` where you have:

```
    var someService = angular.module('someService');
    someService.factory('subService', function () {
        var methodName = function (arg) {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

And in the Angular module with your application logic, do something like:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['someService']);
```

And then ofcourse;

```
mainApp.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, subService) {
    // controller stuff
    subService.methodName(arg); // etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you're asking but, if you have a controller that «needs» to be split in several files, first thing you should consider, before going into the «let's split this controller in several files», is starting to identify pieces that you can put inside services and pieces that you can shove inside directives.

Pieces of logic that do non-UI related processing should go inside a services or several services, that you can then inject on your main controller.

Pieces that have the resposability of doing DOM manipulation or filling DOM elements with data, you should consider putting those inside Directives. Not only you will have a cleaner View but also less chances of violation the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle.

If these don't solve your problem, you can create child controllers and create event emitters to comunicate back and forth between the parent controller and the child controller.

An example of this would be:

HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

       {{title}}
       {{childCtrlMessage}}

       <div ng-controller="child1Ctrl">

           {{subTitle}}
           {{mainCtrlMessage}}

       </div>

    </div>
```

Controller mainCtrl

```
    angular.module('myapp').controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){

        $scope.title = 'Main Controller';

        $scope.$on('myCustomChildEvent',function(data){

              $scope.childCtrlMessage = data.message;   

        });

       $scope.$broadcast('myCustomMainEvent', {mainMessage: 'Hi! I came from the Main Controller', someProperty: someObject /*ignore 'someProperty: someObject', it's just to state the point that you can pass in any data*/});

    });
```

child1Ctrl

```
   angular.module('myapp').controller('child1Ctrl',function($scope){

        $scope.subTitle = 'Child Controller 1'

        $scope.$on('myCustomMainEvent',function(data){

              $scope.mainCtrlMessage = data.mainMessage;   

        });

       $scope.$emit('myCustomChildEvent', {message: 'Hi! I came from the Child 1 Controller!'});

    });
```

Please note that I used $broadcast on the parent controller and $emit on the child controller. You use $broadcast when you want to send data «downwards» , and $emit when you want to send data «upwards».